# Iterate over all fields in custom app / transform code from single field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code which works well inside a custom application I'm building in the app 'Knack'.

However, rather than just save a single field, I'd like to be able to autosave ALL fields in the application.

Is it possible to loop over all 'views' and 'fields' to make this jQuery work on all 'views' and 'fields' in the application?

```
var viewId = "view_19";
var fieldId = "field_31";
var autoSaveDelay = 2000; // Value in milliseconds, 800 = .8 seconds

// Listen to our Article Edit view, when rendered register our actions
$(document).on('knack-view-render.' + viewId, function(event, view, records) {
    console.log(" >>> Rendered view");

    // Temporarily store data for comparison later
    var initialData = $("#" + viewId).find("#" + fieldId).val();

    var timer = {};

    var autoSaveLabel = document.createElement('span');
    autoSaveLabel.id = "autosave_label_" + viewId + "_" + fieldId;
    autoSaveLabel.style = "font-style: italic;";

    // Add autosave checkbox flag to field
    $("#kn-input-" + fieldId).append(autoSaveLabel);

    // Add listener for keyup
    $("#" + viewId).find("#" + fieldId).on('keyup', function() {

        // If the data is the same... don't save it!
        if (initialData !== $("#" + viewId).find("#" + fieldId).val()) {

            // Show edited label
            var autoSaveLabelElement = $("#autosave_label_" + viewId + "_" + fieldId);
            autoSaveLabelElement.html("This field was edited...");
            autoSaveLabelElement.show();

            // Cancel timer if it was already running 
            clearTimeout(timer);

            // Start timer
            timer = setTimeout(function() {

                // Call Knack API to update field
                var data = {};
                data[fieldId] = $("#" + viewId).find("#" + fieldId).val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.knack.com/v1/pages/scene_12/views/' + viewId + '/records/' + records.id,
                    type: 'PUT',
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': Knack.getUserToken(),
                        'X-Knack-Application-Id': Knack.application_id,
                        'X-Knack-REST-API-Key': '6bf3a9a0-caf1-11e8-bbe4-556d6e072f02',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    success: function(records) {
                        console.log(" >>> Auto Saved...");
                        autoSaveLabelElement.html("Automatically saved...");
                        autoSaveLabelElement.fadeOut(autoSaveDelay);

                        // Re-save data in var for future comparisons
                        initialData = $("#" + viewId).find("#" + fieldId).val();
                    }
                });
            }, autoSaveDelay);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign event handler to multiple elements at once.
You can try something like below -

```
var viewId = "view_";
var fieldId = "field_";

var viewIdSelector = $('id^="'+ viewId + '"');
var fieldIdSelector = $('id^="'+fieldId + '"');
$(viewIdSelector).find(fieldIdSelector).on('keyup', function() {
..your logic
}
```

This would work for all views and all fields in the application.

For more information,
http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data

Comment: Interesting. So presumably all references to viewId and fieldId as well as eg, $("#" + viewId).find("#" + fieldId).val(); would need to be changed?